# how to construct graph $G$ where $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

for group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (arbitrary $n$) I want to make a graph $G$ where $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_n$, for $n=2$ it is $P_n$ and $K_2$ (if I am not wrong), how should I construct $G$?

Comment: Is the graph directed?

Comment: no I don't have this assumption,but can we suppose it is directed,after constructing,remove the arrows?

Comment: This might help ref (page 11) (http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs6204/files/Lec5-Automorphisms.pdf).
And cycles won't do. Their automorphism groups are isomorphic to dihedral groups.

Comment: The cycle graph of order $n$ almost works; its automorphism group is the dihedral group $D_n$. You can try to modify it to get rid of the extra reflection symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pdf Uma linked to in the comments gives the idea, but I'll lay it out here.  Basically we want an $n$-cycle, but we don't want there to be reflection symmetry, so take a directed $n$-cycle and replace every directed edge
$$\bullet \to \bullet$$
with the undirected graph
$$\bullet - \overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\bullet}{|}}{\bullet}}{|}}{\bullet} - \overset{\overset{\bullet}{|}}{\bullet} - \bullet$$
It's not hard to see that a graph automorphism must preserve these pieces and their orientation, so this doesn't change the automorphism group.

Comment: thanks,that was beautiful.